# Cursor: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetchall'

Tags: python, mysql, attributeerror, mysql-connector, database-cursor

#### Code

For a cursor-query:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode

config = {
    'user': 'root',
    'password': 'root',
    'host': 'localhost',
    'database': 'myDatabase'}


cn = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
cur = cn.cursor()
emailExist = cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM customerDetails""").fetchall()
print(emailExist)
```

My database file is in the same directory as this script.

#### AttributeError

I get this error:

```
>>> emailExist = cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM customerDetails""").fetchall()

>>> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetchall'
```

#### Expected

When I run the same query in MySQLWorkbench the output is:

```
0 row(s) returned
```

Comment: `execute` doesn’t return anything. Call `fetchall` on the cursor object itself!

Answer (score 2):

See docs [MySQL :: MySQL Connector/Python Developer Guide :: 10.5.6 MySQLCursor.fetchall() Method](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchall.html).

#### Issue

The error-message

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetchall'

for statement

```
cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM customerDetails""")
```

reads:

- the execute-statement returned `None`
- and the return value of `None` doesn't have `fetchall` attribute or method

#### Fix

Execute the cursor-methods in this order:

1. `cur.execute(sql)` to create the cursor (in `cur`, not as return)
2. `cur.fetchall()` to return the result