# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetchall'

Tags: python, attributeerror, mysql-connector, database-cursor

I tried to return the result of an SQL query.

This works perfectly with [pyodbc](https://pypi.org/project/pyodbc/) but not with [mysql-connector](https://pypi.org/project/mysql-connector/).

#### Error Output

```
File "/mySQLDB.py", line 17, in execute_and_fetch
     result = conn.cursor().execute(query, params).fetchall()
     AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetchall'
```

#### Code

```
import mysql.connector

class MYSQLDB:
    def __init__(self):
        self.host = 'xx'
        self.database = 'xx$xx'
        self.user = 'xx'
        self.password = 'xx'

    def execute(self, query, *params):
        mysql.connector.connect(host=self.host, database=self.database,
                         user=self.user, password=self.password).cursor().execute(query, params).commit()

    def execute_and_fetch(self, query, *params):
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(host=self.host, database=self.database,
                         user=self.user, password=self.password)
        result = conn.cursor().execute(query, params).fetchall()
        conn.commit()
        return result
```

Comment: Doesn't the error mean that "conn.cursor().execute(query, params)" returned a None value?

Comment: @BobbyOcean if i understand you well. You are trying to say its not empty recordset ?

Comment: All I know is that your code only uses "fetchall()" in place at that is on the code "conn.cursor().execute(query, params)". Hence, running that .execute() must be returning a None value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cursor: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetchall'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59829195/cursor-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-fetchall)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PEP 249, the DBAPI spec](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#cursor-methods), says that the return value of `execute` is undefined. Quite a few DBAPI implementations return `None`, meaning that you cannot (portably) chain `execute().fetchall()` as you are trying to do.

Comment: Instead use two separate method invocations like explained in this [docs example for MySQLCursor.fetchall](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchall.html):  `cursor.execute(sql); rows = cursor.fetchall()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.
If you are still having problems check that the connection to the database is successful.

```
import mysql.connector

class MYSQLDB:
    def __init__(self):
        self.host = 'xx'
        self.database = 'xx$xx'
        self.user = 'xx'
        self.password = 'xx'

    def execute(self, query, *params):
        mysql.connector.connect(host=self.host, database=self.database,
                         user=self.user, password=self.password).cursor().execute(query, params).commit()

    def execute_and_fetch(self, query, *params):
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(host=self.host, database=self.database,
                         user=self.user, password=self.password)
        
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:

            cursor.execute(query, params=None)
...         result = cursor.fetchall()
            conn.commit()
            return result
```

Comment: `line 18, in execute_and_fetch
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
AttributeError: __enter__`